# This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above. Current version is 21.x.x.

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, sdk

**Hi i have a problem with my Eclipse and the SDK  (i have download and install the latest ADT Bundle for windows )
when i start my eclipse i get this problem :**

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above. Current version is 20.0.0. 
please update your SDK tools to the latest version
```

**i have tried the option  : Help -> check for updates
But with no new update find
then i try this one :**

```
How to Update your ADT to Latest Version

In Eclipse go to Help
Install New Software ---> Add
inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or whatever you want)
and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
after loading you should get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
check both if you want to use the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in the future or check Developer Tool only
click Next
Finish
```

**But i dont have the option to click next to finish  (the back , next and finish options are grey )
Then i try this method :**

```
Go here download latest version of ADT-22.0.4.zip (*)
At Eclipse > Help > Install new software... > Uncheck Contact all update sites during install to find required software (last bottom preference) that will avoid any unwanted delays during install.
then at the same screen (top) Click Add > Archive > select downloaded ADT-X.X.X.zip > follow on screen installation steps
```

**But had the same problem when it was to finish the installation.. no option to click ''next''**

**then i try this one :**

```
Help – Install New Software in the ADT menu.
Type https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml in “Work with:” and Enter.
You can see the “Developer Tools” item.
Select it and click Next.
Click Next one more.
Click Finish accepting the terms of the license agreements.
Click OK in the “Security Warning” window.
Let the installer restart ADT after installing the tools.
```

**But and in this option have the same problem as above..  can click the ''next'' to finish**

http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c316/caslor_1978/diafora/atdproblem_zps0d141b7b.jpg

**i check my version and it is  the latest but have the problem**

http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c316/caslor_1978/diafora/atdproblem2_zps81de6317.jpg

**How can i fix this problem ? any suggestion?**

**Win7 / 32bit /  java SE Development kit7 update 25**

Comment: Check your version of eclipse: Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 22.0.4.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Start Eclipse, then select

> Help > Install New Software.

Click `Add`, in the top-right corner.

In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter `ADT Plugin` for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Click `OK`.

If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click `Next`.

In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click `Next`.
Read and accept the license agreements, then click `Finish`.

If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click `OK`.

When the installation completes, restart Eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last week, I tried everything, but nothing helped me.

Finally fixed it only by re-downloading ADT bundle whole again.

Comment: i have download it 2 times ! but have always the same problem..
how do you remove the previous installation? i check it from my control panel  add remove programs and was not there... so i delete it manually by removing the folder..  is that right ?

Comment: **Deleting should remove it** _(moving to another place is also a good idea because as your updated the platforms will be present in older versions, a quick swap after everything is fixed would save you download time)_, **try adding SDK location through preference/android**

Comment: Thanks my friend i will try these and hope to find a solution.
Thanks for the interesting

Answer (score 0):

Click ADT, then About ADT. You should see your software info. Click the ADT version and then click update.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to download android sdk for your computer. like 32bit or 64 bit. try re - downloading and placing the android sdk into some other folder.
and in future updates. update eclipse first and then android sdk.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how I solved it.

It happened to me because I had previously installed ADT ( in Feb 2012 ) , and therefore the new eclipse.exe from the newly unzipped ADT was pointing to the old SDK Manager.

So I deleted the following folders belonging to the older version:

- From C:\Users\*your_name*\ , delete **.android** and **.android-sdk** . I forgot the exact name of the second folder, but basically you have to delete android related stuff from there.
- Also delete **.metadata** from workspace. You may keep your old project folders.